# Example of strictly convex space with not strictly smooth dual

Tags: convex-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to find an example of a space $V$ which is strictly convex, but has a dual space $V^*$ which is not strictly smooth. Any help please?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what *strictly smooth* means. I know that *smooth* means the uniqueness of the norming functional for every nonzero element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As any separable space, $\ell_1$ admits an equivalent strictly convex norm. Indeed, since the identity map from $\ell_1$ to $\ell_2$ is bounded, we can take $\|x\|_1+\|x\|_2$ as such a norm. The dual of this strictly convex space is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$. But [M.M. Day proved in 1955](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-078-02/S0002-9947-1955-0067351-1/home.html) (see Theorem 9) that $\ell_\infty$ does not admit any equivalent smooth norm.