# Example of a strictly convex set in $\ell_\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $\ell_\infty$ be the space of bounded sequences equipped with the supremum norm.

Are there any strictly convex subsets of $\ell_\infty$ that have non-empty interior? (The last condition is to rule out trivial examples such as singletons.)

The unit ball of $\ell_\infty$ is not strictly convex, and $\ell_\infty$ is not separable, so I can't use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195496/260904).

A strictly convex set $C$, by the way, is a convex set whose boundary contains no open line segment, i.e. $x,y \in \partial C$ implies $\{\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y: \alpha \in (0,1)\} \subset$ int$C$.

Comment: A set with nonempty interior contains a ball. So it cannot be compact.

Comment: The Minkowski sum of the $\ell_\infty$ and the $\ell_2$ unit balls should be strictly convex (according to my intuition, I did not check).

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x):= \sum_n \frac1{n^2}x_n^2$. Then $f:l^\infty\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and strictly convex. And the set $\{x\in l^\infty: \ f(x) <1\}$ is strictly convex with non-empty interior. Note that $x\mapsto \sqrt{f(x)}$ is a strictly convex norm on $l^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. How'd you come up with that?

Comment: I was looking for a element-wise quadratic and continuous function from $l^\infty\to \mathbb R$. Then sublevel sets will have the desired property.

Comment: Is there a way of tweaking this so that the set doesn't contain a pointwise minimum (in this case $0$)?

Comment: Also, how did you know that sub level sets of an element wise quadratic and continuous function would have the desired properties? Any references you can point me to would be much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Pre-images for continous functions of open sets are open, sub-level sets of convex functions are convex.